# How to write update query using Inner join

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2003

I have this query

```
Update ProductionDetails P Inner join 
(   SELECT Distinct A.BaseCode, A.BaseScale, (A.BaseScale * B.BasePer / 100)  AS BaseVal,  A.TreadCode, A.TreadScale, (A.TreadScale * B.TreadPer / 100) as TreadVal,  A.InterfaceCode, A.LipCode, A.LipScale,
    (A.LipScale * B.HsPer / 100) as LipVal, A.CenterCode, A.CenterScale, (A.CenterScale * B.CenterPer / 100) AS CenterVal,  A.StencilNo 
                  from productionDetails A  inner join 
                           BlendMaster B on (A.InterfaceCode = b.Category AND A.BaseCode = B.Base AND A.TreadCode = B.Tread AND A.centerCode = B.center)  
          Where B.Status = yes
) AS ResTable on ( P.StencilNo = ResTable.StencilNo ) 
        Set P.BaseValue = ResTable.BaseVal, P.TreadValue = ResTable.TreadVal , P.LipValue = ResTable.LipVal, P.CenterValue = ResTable.CenterVal
```

I need to update **ProductionDetails** table on **BaseValue, TreadValue, CenterValue, LipValue** Fields with the calculated value in ***(SELECT Query ... ) AS ResTable*** .

if i write command to *select from ResTable* i get value, but if i update it says error "Operation must use an updateable query". i need to run this on **MS Access 2013**

Here is the query for sample data

```
CREATE TABLE ProductionDetails(StencilNo Text, LipCode Text, LipScale Text,LipValue Number,BaseCode Text,BaseScale Number,BaseValue Number,InterfaceCode Text,CenterCode Text,CenterScale Number,CenterValue Number,TreadCode Text,TreadScale Number,TreadValue Number)

Create Table BlendMaster (Category Text, Base Text, BasePer number , HsPer number, Center text,  CenterPer number,  Tread text, TreadPer number)

Insert into ProductionDetails (StencilNo, LipCode , LipScale  ,BaseCode ,BaseScale , InterfaceCode ,CenterCode , CenterScale , TreadCode ,TreadScale  ) 
VALUES ('C160405234', '-', 0,'BFA10',48.44,'BF10+CEG28' , 'CEG28', 36.5, 'TRR51', 52.56)

Insert into BlendMaster (Category, Base, BasePer ,HsPer, Center , CenterPer , Tread,TreadPer  ) 
VALUES ('BF10+CEG28', 'BFA10',25, 25, 'CEG28', 15, 'TRR51', 18)
```

Answer (score 2):

i think update should be done like this

```
  UPDATE p 
SET    P.basevalue = ResTable.baseval, 
       P.treadvalue = ResTable.treadval, 
       P.lipvalue = ResTable.lipval, 
       P.centervalue = ResTable.centerval 
       from 
#productiondetails P 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT  A.basecode, 
                                   A.basescale, 
                                   ( A.basescale * B.baseper / 100 )     AS 
                                   BaseVal, 
                                   A.treadcode, 
                                   A.treadscale, 
                                   ( A.treadscale * B.treadper / 100 )   AS 
                                   TreadVal, 
                                   A.interfacecode, 
                                   A.lipcode, 
                                   A.lipscale, 
                                   ( A.lipscale * B.hsper / 100 )        AS 
                                   LipVal, 
                                   A.centercode, 
                                   A.centerscale, 
                                   ( A.centerscale * B.centerper / 100 ) AS 
                                   CenterVal, 
                                   A.stencilno 
                   FROM   #productiondetails A 
                          INNER JOIN #blendmaster B 
                                  ON  A.interfacecode = b.category 
                                       AND A.basecode = B.base  
                                       AND A.centercode = B.center  )
                   ---WHERE  B.status = 'yes' this condtiton is not present in yout 2 tables)
         ResTable 
               ON  P.stencilno = ResTable.stencilno
```

Comment: I tried this way also it says syntax error near " from keyword "

Comment: When i test the format i run another query " Update  ProductionDetails P inner Join BlendMaster B on ( P.InterfaceCode = B.Category And P.TreadCode = B.Tread And P.CenterCode = B.Center  )   Set P.BaseValue = 3.5   WHERE P.StencilNo='C141200864' " same structure as above, it executd successfully,

Comment: @Bala your inner query returning any data can u check once

Comment: yeah it returns value, i checked it now also.

Comment: please copy same code what i edited now and check it..@Bala

Comment: Same Error "Syntax Error(Missing Operator) " near from keyworkd

Comment: with this code we will not recieve like this errors i think so else add some data and your output..@Bala

Comment: @Chanukya OP Says he want to run that query on MS Access 2013

Comment: @Chanukya i have edited the code, try with single row.

Comment: @Chanukya Same error repeats.  This query may run successfull in sql server, i think the syntax for "Update with inner join" in ms-access is differ from sql server. I need to execute query in Ms-access.

Comment: upvoted @chanukya, And thanks for your time and help.